# Execute sql script inside seed.rb in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I want to execute this sql script inside my seed.rb

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/list-38.csv'
INTO TABLE list
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(email,name,password);
```

I checked this link but unable to figure out the solution.So that once we run rake db:seed

[How to seed mysql database by running sql scripts in Ruby Rails platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804891/how-to-seed-mysql-database-by-running-sql-scripts-in-ruby-rails-platform) it dumps my data into the table.

any queries ..do reply

Thanx

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this in *db/seeds.rb* to execute raw SQL with *rake db:seed*

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
connection.execute("*_YOUR_SQL_HERE_*")
```

Comment: Hello, Paul. What if I want to add a second sql query for another table, or even more tables? Should I add a new line? `connection.execute("*_2nd_SQL_HERE_*")`  and comment the 1st line?

Answer (score 7):

For multiple sql statements, I ended up iterating over each statement separately:

```
# db/seeds.rb

connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()

sql = <<-EOL
  INSERT INTO users values ('Admin');
  INSERT INTO categories values ('Supervisors');
EOL

sql.split(';').each do |s|
  connection.execute(s.strip) unless s.strip.empty?
end
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for that. Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

A variation on Fredrik Boström's answer that can load from a file:

```
# db/seeds.rb

def execute_sql_file(path, connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection)
  require 'active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb'
  IO.read(path).split(';').reject(&:blank?).each do |statement|
    connection.execute(statement)
  end
end

execute_sql_file('my.sql')
```

Answer (score 1):

Super late to this answer but hopefully it helps someone in my position. Instead of iterating over each sql statement you can use .execute_batch using a direct connection to your database with the database version you are using. Below is an example with SQLite3.

```
#db/seeds.rb

DB = {:conn => SQLite3::Database.new("./db/development.sqlite")}

sql = <<-EOL
  INSERT INTO users values ('Admin');
  INSERT INTO categories values ('Supervisors');
EOL

DB[:conn].execute_batch(sql)
```